# How to test bit in OData

Tags: bit-manipulation, odata

OData does not include any bit-manipulation operators.

Is there a way to create a $filter equivalent to

```
column & mask = mask
column & mask = 0
```

with the available odata operators?
add, sub, div, mul, mod, neg, round, floor, ceiling

In my case `mask` can only contain a single bit

One idea I got is to declare a generic "flags" enum (e.g. Bits.Bit1, Bits.Bit2) and then use `cast` + `has` but don't know if it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to test integers for bits on/off via the OData v4 interface.

A `flags` enum work fine but integers can't be casted to an enum. I.e. you must expose the column as an enum in the metadata.

Answer (score 0):

In case if you need only checking that entity Enum properties contains any of [Flags] values, you can use 'has' operator.

http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata/v4.0/cs02/part2-url-conventions/odata-v4.0-cs02-part2-url-conventions.html#_Toc372793313